# regular expression which can treat a string containing '#' as illegal input

Tags: regex

I wrote a regular expression `(https?:\/\/)+([a-x]*)?.[a-z]*.(com|io|cn|net)` that can achieve:

1. Must start with http or https
2. Must end with com,cn,io or net
3. Domain names can only consist of numbers, letters, and underscores
4. Subdomain can be empty
   the right answer can be 'http://123.cn' or 'https://www.123.cn'

but it also considered 'http://ww#.123.com' as the correct answer,
I wonder what's wrong with my expression, how to limit input '#'.

Comment: Try: `^https?://(?:www\.)?\w+(?:\.\w+)*\.(?:com|io|cn|net)$`

Comment: Dot `.`  has a special meaning in java regex meaning "any character". If you only want to allow literal dots at that place and not any character you need to escape the dot in your regex.

Comment: 'https?:\/\/(\w+\.)?(\w)*\.(com|cn|io|net)' is also a right answer.   '\w'  represents any letter, number or underscore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a RegEx tester online (like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com)) it will tell you that it's matching because the `.` is not escaped as `\.` so it will match the `#` character.

Try: `^(https?:\/\/)([a-z0-9_]*\.)?[a-z0-9_]*\.(com|io|cn|net)$` and you may get what you're looking for.

Note your original RegEx did not include digits or the underscore in the domain names.